# Sublime text: Select text with parentheses

Tags: sublimetext3

Just a little question:

How can I select this kind of text using keyboard in Sublime text 3:

```
r(b)
```

or this:

```
r(margins).
```

I tried with `Ctrl+d` or `Ctrl+Shift+space` but not select all the text.

Thanks in advance
Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex.

```
r\([^}]*\)
```

---

Follow the guideline on
[Column Selection](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html) page.

If you are using macOS, click on the text and  then `ctrl + shift + arrow left/right`.

Comment: Thanks but I ask for select text with keyboard